# Blazor Server : How to access css file(s) of RazorClassLibrary from Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

In my sample Blazor server project, I'm using dynamic assembly loading, to load my RazorClassLibrary dll file into my main blazor server project. This works correctly but i don't know how to load static files of my razorClassLibrary project such as css.
Where is the problem & how to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can see here some examples, these are for Blazor Wasm but it's the same concept
https://github.com/elgransan/BlazorPluginComponents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Razor Class library is called `Library`.

Set a dependency in the web project to the class library.

Add a link in `_Layout.cshtml`

```
    <link href="_content/library/css/library.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Note that's: _content/*project-name*/*where-off-wwwroot*

Here's a screenshot showing the browser Dev tools:
[image]